# Why is sort -u -n losing non-unique lines?

Tags: sort

I was trying to sort a list using numerical order, and only keep unique lines, and thought `sort -n -u` would do the job. But surprisingly enough, this removes non-unique lines. Am I missing something here, or is it a bug in `sort`?

Compare:

```
$ java_home -l | sort -u | sort -n
/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

with:

```
$ java_home -l | sort -u -n
/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64
```

`java_home` is the script I'm trying to write; the actual behavior does not really matter for this question, only that it always outputs the two lines shown in the first example.

Why are the two command lines not equivalent?

I'm using

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: using `-V` (--version-sort) instead of `-n` might perhaps work for your case.

Comment: The `-u` option removes all but unique lines.  Try reading the man page to find out what the options do.  Look before you leap.

Comment: @user10489  That is not so. `-u` does not remove all lines that have duplicates: it removes enough duplicates that it leaves one copy of such lines, not zero copies. And in fact, it does not even do that: it only considers the specified key fields to determine uniqueness, not the complete line. So it does remove fewer records that you state, and more than you expect.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant that's pedantic.  :-P  At any rate, the correct answer is in the man page.

Comment: @user10489  Pity the question is closed -- I have a test that surprised me. My man page is seriously ambiguous -- it says `--unique: Output only the first  of an equal run`. (a) It does not state that the equality refers only to the specified key fields, not to the complete record (as `uniq` would do). (b) It does not output the "first": the -u check is done when the keys are compared during the sort, so which record is kept depends on the merging after presort, not which is "first" in the input.

Comment: Odd.  Sort is suppose to be a stable sort.

Comment: You could add your findings to the question this is a duplicate of, where it seems appropriate.

Comment: @user10489  Man page has a separate option `--stable` which says `stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison`. Unclear how this interacts with -u though. I learned to be very wary of sort args and locale.